List of numbers in an arithmetic progression
I need to generate a list of numbers in an arithmetic progression. For example 3,7,11,15,19.
I was hopeful there was a way to achieve this by specifying the first term (a), the common difference (d) and the number of terms (n). For example ArithProg{3}{4}{5} would produce 3,7,11,15,19.
I used ChatGPT to produce the code below, and it looks pretty good, though I continued to get error messages.
Any thoughts? Thanks so much!
\documentclass{article}

% Define a command to generate a list of terms in an arithmetic progression
\newcommand{\ArithProg}[3]{%
    \foreach \n in {0,...,#3}{%
        \ifnum\n=0%
            #1%
        \else%
            , \the\numexpr#1+#2*\n\relax%
        \fi%
    }%
}

\begin{document}

% Usage: \ArithProg{first term}{common difference}{number of terms}
\[ \ArithProg{3}{4}{5} \]

\end{document}


Any particular errors or just general grumbling about life? As a rule of thumb, do not ask ChatGPT for TeX code. It isn't good at writing it. Sometimes it is staggeringly peculiar. I find it hard to believe this generates any useful output at all. It appears to have forgotten to tell you to load pgffor, though, if you are using tikz, you're already loading it.

Apparently, somebody has told ChatGPT that uncommented line-endings can cause spurious spaces. Unfortunately, nobody seems to have informed it that a space or (equivalently) an uncommented end-of-line is sometimes required for TeX to parse the input correctly. In this case, 0% is wrong, for example.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
% Define a command to generate a list of terms in an arithmetic progression
\newcommand{\ArithProg}[3]{%
    \foreach \n in {0,...,#3}{%
        \ifnum\n=0
            #1%
        \else%
            , \the\numexpr#1+#2*\n\relax
        \fi
    }%
}

\begin{document}

% Usage: \ArithProg{first term}{common difference}{number of terms less one}
\[ \ArithProg{3}{4}{5} \]

\end{document}

However, the code is peculiar because the conditional isn't needed. Zero times anything is zero, so why treat the first case specially? The only actual need for this is to get a comma.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
% Define a command to generate a list of terms in an arithmetic progression
\newcommand{\ArithProg}[3]{%
    \foreach \n in {0,...,#3}{%
        \ifnum\n>0 , \fi
        \the\numexpr#1+#2*\n\relax
    }%
}

\begin{document}

% Usage: \ArithProg{first term}{common difference}{number of terms less one}
\[ \ArithProg{3}{4}{5} \]

\end{document}

There are, however, friendlier ways of doing this in LaTeX.
EDIT
If you want the output to automatically line-break, don't put it into \[ ... \]. Then the output will be typeset as text. For example,
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
% Define a command to generate a list of terms in an arithmetic progression
\newcommand{\ArithProg}[3]{%
    \foreach \n in {0,...,#3}{%
        \ifnum\n=0
            #1%
        \else%
            , \the\numexpr#1+#2*\n\relax
        \fi
    }%
}

\begin{document}

% Usage: \ArithProg{first term}{common difference}{number of terms less one}
 \ArithProg{3}{4}{35} 

\end{document}

If you want line-breaks but the numbers to be in maths mode, make the commas text and the numbers maths. For example,
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
% Define a command to generate a list of terms in an arithmetic progression
\newcommand{\ArithProg}[3]{%
    \foreach \n in {0,...,#3}{$
        \ifnum\n=0
            #1%
        \else%
            $, $\the\numexpr#1+#2*\n\relax
        \fi
    $}%
}

\begin{document}

% Usage: \ArithProg{first term}{common difference}{number of terms less one}
 \ArithProg{3}{4}{35} 

\end{document}

Here's one using LaTeX's \inteval rather than \numexpr. As far as I can tell, there are no user-level macros for loops in the current kernel and, though I thought there was something for integer comparisons, if there is, it eludes me now. (The documentation is currently somewhat fragmented, so I'm very likely looking in the wrong place. It is hard to keep track of so many PDFs.)
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
% Define a command to generate a list of terms in an arithmetic progression
\newcommand{\ArithProg}[3]{%
  \foreach \n in {0,...,#3}{%
    \ifnum\n=0
      1%
    \else
      , \inteval{#1+#2*\n}%
    \fi
  }%
}

\begin{document}

% Usage: \ArithProg{first term}{common difference}{number of terms less one}
 \ArithProg{3}{4}{35} 

\end{document}

Alternatively, you could drop to the expl3 programming layer, use ifthen or use the pgfmath conditional operator (but the syntax is more complex, if I remember correctly).
Note that all the above can be used in text or maths mode, except for the one which puts each number into maths mode. (Actually, even that would work, I think. Just it would put the commas into maths mode and the numbers into text mode, which would be odd.) So if you want multiple lines of output auto-wrapped, don't wrap the macro in a maths (or any other) environment which will prevent that. Inline maths or text should work OK.

+1. Do you know the reason for the strange effects if  in place of pgffor we use tikz  which also defines \foreach?

@PrzemysławScherwentke What strange effects? tikz doesn't 'also' define it. It loads exactly the same code. tikz \foreach just is the \foreach from pgffor. So if I substitute tikz for pgffor, I get precisely the same output as far as I can tell. What am I looking for?

How to modify the newcommand if I want only 10 terms of the progression for each line?

@RaffaeleSantoro You don't need to modify it. Just use 9 as the third argument. The final argument just is to determine the number of terms. So e.g. \ArithProg{3}{4}{9} will produce the first 10 terms.

Thanks so much!

@cfr If I ask for '\ArithProg{3}{4}{35}' I lost many terms that dont have the place to be written in the same line.

@cff Sorry, the codes were different. I understand now.

@RaffaeleSantoro See edit.

@cfr Great! (--->#1).

Just for the sake of variety, here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution.

Observe that \ArithProg can be used in both text and math mode.
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\ArithProg[3]{\directlua{ 
     zz = #1+#2*(#3-1) % compute final element of sequence
     for i=#1,zz,#2 do 
        if i==zz then tex.sprint( i ) % no trailing comma 
        else tex.sprint( i .. ", " ) 
        end
     end 
     }}
     
\begin{document}
\ArithProg{3}{4}{5}; $\ArithProg{-6}{2}{7}$.
\end{document}


They all work in text or maths mode ;).

Calculating the final one is definitely neater, though. I was lazy.

cfr has already commented about the case of “missing required space syndrome”
Here I present a fully expandable set of macros that does the job and is readily modifiable for geometric progressions.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\arithprog}{mmm}
 {% #1 = first term, #2 = common difference, #3 = number of terms
  \int_compare:nT { #3 > 0 } { \wendy_arithprog:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \wendy_arithprog:nnn
 {
  % the first term
  #1
  % the other terms
  \__wendy_arithprog:nenn { #2 } { \int_eval:n { #1+#2 } } { 1 } { #3 }
 }
  
\cs_new:Nn \__wendy_arithprog:nnnn
 {
  \int_compare:nT { #3 < #4 }
   {
    % the term
    ,~#2
    % possibly the next one
    \__wendy_arithprog:neen { #1 } { \int_eval:n { #1+#2 } } { \int_eval:n { #3 + 1 } } { #4 }
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__wendy_arithprog:nnnn { nenn, neen }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
\arithprog{1}{1}{10} \\
\arithprog{-4}{2}{5} \\
\arithprog{10}{-2}{5}
\end{gather}

\edef\test{\arithprog{0}{0}{10}}

\texttt{|\meaning\test|}

\edef\test{\arithprog{100}{-20}{0}}

\texttt{|\meaning\test|}

\end{document}


For geometric progressions, we can just add as an argument the operation to employ.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\arithprog}{mmm}
 {% #1 = first term, #2 = common difference, #3 = number of terms
  \int_compare:nT { #3 > 0 } { \wendy_prog:nnnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { + } }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\geomprog}{mmm}
 {% #1 = first term, #2 = common factor, #3 = number of terms
  \int_compare:nT { #3 > 0 } { \wendy_prog:nnnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { * } }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \wendy_prog:nnnn
 {% #4 is the operation
  % the first term
  #1
  % the other terms
  \__wendy_prog:nennn { #2 } { \int_eval:n { (#1) #4 (#2) } } { 1 } { #3 } { #4 }
 }
  
\cs_new:Nn \__wendy_prog:nnnnn
 {% #5 is the operation
  \int_compare:nT { #3 < #4 }
   {
    % the term
    ,~#2
    % possibly the next one
    \__wendy_prog:neenn { #1 } { \int_eval:n { (#1) #5 (#2) } } { \int_eval:n { #3 + 1 } } { #4 } { #5 }
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__wendy_prog:nnnnn { ne, nee }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
\arithprog{1}{1}{10} \\
\arithprog{-4}{2}{5} \\
\arithprog{10}{-2}{5} \\[2ex]
\geomprog{1}{1}{10} \\
\geomprog{1}{2}{10} \\
\geomprog{-1}{-1}{5}
\end{gather}

\edef\test{\arithprog{0}{0}{10}}

\texttt{|\meaning\test|}

\edef\test{\arithprog{100}{-20}{0}}

\texttt{|\meaning\test|}

\edef\test{\geomprog{1}{1}{10}}

\texttt{|\meaning\test|}

\edef\test{\geomprog{100}{-20}{0}}

\texttt{|\meaning\test|}

\end{document}


